# Implications on the relation between signs of random variables

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Consider a binary random variable $Z$ and a random variable $Y$.

Suppose that the following relations hold
$$
Z=1 \Rightarrow Y\in \mathbb{R}^{+}_0\\
Z=0 \Rightarrow Y\in \mathbb{R}^{-}_0
$$
In words, the relations read as: "if $Z$ takes value $1$, then $Y$ takes necessarily a value greater than or equal to zero"; "if $Z$ takes value $0$, then $Y$ takes necessarily a value smaller than or equal to zero"

I believe that the following implications are correct, but I would like to have your confirmation:

- 1. $E(Y|Z=1)\geq 0$
- 2. $E(Y|Z=0)\leq 0$
- 3. $E(ZY)\geq 0$ [this is implied by 1, provided that 1 holds]
- 4. $E((1-Z)Y)\leq 0$ [this is implied by 2, provided that 2 holds]
- 5. $E((2Z-1)Y)\geq 0$

Comment: You seem to be assuming for the first two that $0 < P(Z=1) < 1$.  Apart from that these look reasonable, though it is possible some of these expectations are infinite.

Comment: None of these expectations need even exist.  When they do, could you explain where you might be having trouble with any of the demonstrations?